# mysql: cannot create user after delete the user with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, createuser

I was trying to create a mysql user with:

```
$ mysql5 -u root -p
$ [enter password]
$ create user 'name'@'localhost' indentified by '123456';
```

Then I accidentally deleted the user while using phpMyAdmin.

So I came back to terminal to create the user again with the lines above. Then it gives me an error:

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'name'@'localhost'
```

How do I fix this? I need to create the user with the same name and password.

Thanks in advance,

Milo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very hard to see the issue here without some testing, but you may want to try:

```
flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a user using a tool such as MySQL admin or Mysql Workbench, it is not enough to delete the row in the table 'user'.
You have to drop the user as using the following sentence:

```
DROP USER user [, user] ...
```

you can check more information here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-user.html

Here is an example:

```
DROP USER 'usertodelete'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You can check if everything went well with:

```
use mysql;

select * from user;
```

Best!